# How to check if more site is indexed in Google

Tags: php, indexed

I found one script check index on google if site have indexed

```
function getPagesIndexedGoogle($site)
{
    if ($site) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site:$site&amp;gws_rd=ssl",
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
        ));
        $result_string = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if (strpos($result_string, "did not match any documents") !== false) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            $match = preg_match("/about ([0-9,]{0,12})/i", $result_string, $matches);

            echo $matches[1];
        }
    }
}

if($_POST['domain']){
    $site = $_POST['domain'];
}
echo  $_POST['domain'] ;
echo getPagesIndexedGoogle($site);    

?>
```

How to check mutilple url?

I have used Foreach but it does not work. Please help me.

Comment: `$sites = array("site1","site2","site3"); foreach($sites as $site){ echo getPagesIndexedGoogle($site); }` - Replace array values with real websites of course.

Comment: goggle actively detects scrapers, expect that to be blocked, very quickly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Form let get Data.<form method="POST" action="result.php">
Domain : 
<textarea cols="30" rows="5" wrap="virtual" maxlength="100" name="domain"></textarea><br />

<input type="submit" />

</form>

Comment: Can you show me code let get Array ?

Comment: That will require a lot more work. You'll need to split the websites, check for valid input, etc etc. How are websites entered? Is each website on a new line or is there a space character between each of them? All in all you're asking for trouble. You don't control how users enter websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, this should do the trick:

```
<?php

function getPagesIndexedGoogle($site)
{
    if ($site) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=site:$site&amp;gws_rd=ssl",
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=> false,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
        ));
        $result_string = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        if (strpos($result_string, "did not match any documents") !== false) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            $match = preg_match("/about ([0-9,]{0,12})/i", $result_string, $matches);

            echo $matches[1];
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($_POST['domain'])){

    // Tries to split URLs by new line or space character
    $sites = preg_split('#\\r\\n|\\r|\\n| #i', $_POST['domain']);

    foreach($sites as $site){
        // Checks if the URL is a valid website or not (http(s):// must be included!)
        if(preg_match('#((https?|ftp):\/\/(\S*?\.\S*?))([\s)\[\]{},;"\':<]|\.\s|$)#i', $site)){
            echo $site;
            echo getPagesIndexedGoogle($site);
        } else {
            echo $site;
            echo " is not a valid url.";
        }
    }

} else {
    echo "No websites were entered.";
}

?>
```

I still suggest you don't use a textarea but simple textfields instead. It's just less prone to errors.

Comment: Dear icecub, I used code of you but show error : unexpected '{' .I finded row if(preg_match but didn't look error. Please help me

Comment: @Steven It was a simple error. Fixed it. Code above should work now.

Comment: @Steven If my answer helped you out, please mark it as answered. This is a way of showing your appreciating to the one that helped you out and it will also make sure your question doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Comment: Yup, I was do it.Thanks again